# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic> returns a null object

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, jsonconvert

I hope you can help me. I'm trying to deserialize a response object into a dynamic object in C#. The code goes as follow:

```
var result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

foreach (dynamic backgroundTaskURL in response)
{
    filaUPloads.Add(backgroundTaskURL.href);
}
```

The response dynamic object above has the following value:

```
{{
    "href": "/me/background-tasks/77fa9922-5a1b-4fce-ada4-7c5c5d093270"
}}
```

At the first foreach interaction, the backgroundTaskURL dynamic object reads:

```
{
    "href": "/me/background-tasks/77fa9922-5a1b-4fce-ada4-7c5c5d093270"
}
```

For some reason I'm not able to understand, the backgroundTaskURL dynamic object is not resolving the "href" property.

Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: You've encountered one of the problems with `dynamic` -- you never know what you have.  In your case the returned `response` is **not an array** it's a single object, so you need to do `filaUPloads.Add(response.href);` without the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Newtonsoft.Json, you could use a JObject instead, which I believe is just a JSON-map-like abstraction over a dynamic object.

```cs
var result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(result);

foreach (var backgroundTaskURL in response)
{
    filaUPloads.Add(backgroundTaskURL["href"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 public class ListRecev
    {
        public string href { get; set; }

    }
  var resultjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListRecev>(result);
  foreach (var backgroundTaskURL in resultjson)
  {
   filaUPloads.Add(backgroundTaskURL.href);
  }
```